# Mysql Stored procedure issue with varchar variable in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, where-clause, varchar

I have a problem in mysql stored procedures where the varchar variable in the where clause doesn't return the results. The query is given below.

```
declare itcode varchar(30);
declare qty int;
declare finished int;
declare testc cursor for 
    select itemcode from mytable limit 0,10;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
open testc;
read_loop:Loop
    fetch testc into itcode;
    if finished=1 then
        leave read_loop;
    end if;
    select sum(Qty) as total from 
            mytable2 
            where itemcode=itcode;
end loop;
close testc;
```

In the above statement It returns null even though the item code exists on both tables. however if I write the statement with the manually assigned value on the where close as below it works.

```
select sum(Qty) as total from mytable2 where itemcode='p2343';
```

I'm unable to figure out why the varchar variable doesn't work on the where clause. Can someone let me help me to figure out how to resolve this type issue?

NOTE: Both tables columns are varchar(30).

Additional Note: When I change the statement as below, it prints the values in the itcode as well.

```
select sum(Qty) as total,itcode from mytable2 where itemcode=itcode
```

So the itcode have the value 'p2343' but the above stored procedure is not working.

Comment: is `where itemcode like 'p2343';` works?

Comment: yes, when I give as string with single quotes it works. But when i assign the variable it didn't work.

Comment: and what about `where itemcode like itcode;` ?

Comment: Tried that as well, Didn't work.

Comment: Seems your `itcode` doesn't has value 'p2343'.

Comment: When I type as "select sum(Qty) as total,itcode from 
            mytable2 
            where itemcode=itcode" it prints the values of the itcode. So it has the values.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you can try declaring variable preceding with `@` like, `@itcode`

Comment: Tired that too. Are there any other ways to resolve this issue?

Comment: What if you specify charset **itcode varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8**?

Comment: Tried the itcode varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8, didn't work. Is there anyway to convert the sql string to execute and get the result to the variable? Then I should be able to get a result i guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem here is that the procedure is referencing your global variable `qty` in favour of the `Qty` column on your `mytable2`. Try changing this:

```
declare qty int;
```

to this

```
declare v_qty int;
```

Comment: thanks alot. I was googling all over the place to resolve this. Just to understand, wont the mysql identify the case differences in the field and variable?

Comment: Usually depends on the OS. Unix=yes, Windows & Mac OS=no. Check out this for more info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html